# Sort an NSDictionary into an NSMutableArray but keep value and key?

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsarray, nsdictionary

I'm a little confused: trying to take a list of player names and scores that I have in an NSDictionary, and sort them into score order (highest score first). I know I can't sort a Dictionary so I need to move the data into an array first, but in doing so, won't I have to lose one half of each dictionary key/value pair?

For example, let's say I have the following pairs:

```
Bill / 10000
John / 7500
Stan / 7500
Mark / 5000
```

If I go and take the scores out and sort them, then retrieve the keys later, won't John and Stan get mixed up since they had identical scores? Might it call one of them twice, etc?

I realise I can't sort the dictionary, but is there a smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you could do is to get a sorted array of your players based on their score, and then create a dictionary for each player and append them in another array. Something like this perhaps (I'm using the new literals syntax, use the old one if appropriate):

```
NSDictionary *scores = @{
    @"Stan" : @7500,
    @"Mark" : @5000,
    @"John" : @7500,
    @"Bill" : @10000
};

NSArray *sp = [scores keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2){
    return [obj2 compare:obj1];
}];

NSMutableArray *players = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
for (NSString *p in sp) [players addObject:@{ @"name":p, @"score":scores[p] }];
```

Now your `players` array is:

```
(
        {
        name = Bill;
        score = 10000;
    },
        {
        name = John;
        score = 7500;
    },
        {
        name = Stan;
        score = 7500;
    },
        {
        name = Mark;
        score = 5000;
    }
)
```

PS. Is not a good idea to keep a dictionary where the keys are player names, consider that you got 2 different `John` players... what would happen then? Also a better solution imo would be to create a `Player` class and keep their data (score, name etc) as properties.

Comment: This does work, but would you be able to clarify how the `for` loop works here? I think the syntax is confusing me a little, is this the new stuff (the `@{}` block?)

Comment: `@{}` is just an `NSDictionary` literal. The expanded code would look like this:`[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    p, @"name", [scores valueForKey:p], @"score", nil];`. I hope that this makes sense... For more info on ObjC literals take a look here: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create two arrays, one for the score and another for the player.  The key point being that the player array is in the same order as the (sorted) score array.  The implementation below assumes you keep the score using an `NSNumber` object, and is not particularly efficient as it sorts the values twice:

(untested)

```
NSDictionary *dict = ...;    // key=player (NSString), value=score (NSNumber).

NSArray *scores = [[dict allValues] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    return [(NSNumber *)obj2 compare:(NSNumber *)obj1];
}];

NSArray *players = [dict keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    return [(NSNumber *)obj2 compare:(NSNumber *)obj1];
}];
```

Comment: This throws up a ton of errors. Doesn't expect to see an NSComparisonResult, etc. etc. If I'm sorting one by score, I can't sort the other one by the same thing, can I? What I'm saying is that if I split names and scores into two arrays and sort either of them, they're immediately out of sync, no?

Comment: No, because you are sorting the players in the dictionary using their scores (`keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:`).  I will fix the syntax errors.